# XPath: Forms with Unique IDs

Tags: xpath

I am trying to use XPath as part of a data scraper in order to scrape random comments from reddit for a project. The problem is, the comment forms have unique IDs that change on every page and within comment indent levels. I'm not sure how to make XPath target all of the comment fields with these different IDs.

An example is shown below:

```
//form[@id='form-t1_cj8cyupxa3']/div

//form[@id='form-t1_cj8e0iyx6w']/div
```

Comment: You should provide an example of the html code too.

Answer (score 1):

If there is some pattern to the id then  try e.g. `//form[starts-with(@id, 'form-')]/div`